# Unknown column 'PROGRAMMEDescription' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a servlet which makes a query to a database, but when it runs, I get this error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'PROGRAMMEDescription' in 'field list'

The code:

```java
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String requestType= request.getParameter("requestType");
if (requestType == null) {
    createDynPage(response, "Μη έγκυρος τύπος ερωτήματος");
}

if (requestType.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")) {
    String descr = request.getParameter("descr");
    String mins = request.getParameter("mins");
    String sms = request.getParameter("sms");
    String mb = request.getParameter("mb");
    String pagio = request.getParameter("pagio");
    String minstoall = request.getParameter("minstoall");
    String costpermin = request.getParameter("costpermin");
    String costpersms= request.getParameter("costpersms");
    String costpermb = request.getParameter("costpermb");
    int m = Integer.parseInt(mins);
    int s = Integer.parseInt(sms);
    int d = Integer.parseInt(mb);
    float fc=Float.parseFloat(pagio);
    int mta = Integer.parseInt(minstoall);
    float cpm=Float.parseFloat(costpermin);
    float cps=Float.parseFloat(costpersms);
    float cpmb=Float.parseFloat(costpermb);
    
    try {
        Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
        
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
       
        String insertStmt = "INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (PROGRAMMEDescription, PROGRAMMESpeechTime, PROGRAMMESMSNumber, PROGRAMMEData, PROGRAMMEFixedCost, PROGRAMMESpeechTimeToAll, PROGRAMMECostPerMinute, PROGRAMMECostPerSMS, PROGRAMMECostPerMB)" +
                " VALUES (";
        insertStmt += "'" + descr + "',";
        insertStmt +=  m + ",";
        insertStmt +=  s + ",";
        insertStmt +=  d + ",";
        insertStmt +=  fc + ",";
        insertStmt +=  mta + ",";
        insertStmt +=  cpm + ",";
        insertStmt +=  cps + ",";
        insertStmt +=  cpmb + ")";
        
        stmt.executeUpdate(insertStmt);
        createDynPage(response, "Το πρόγραμμα δημιουργήθηκε επιτυχώς!");
        stmt.close();
    
        con.close();
        
    } catch(SQLException sqle) {
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
    
} else {
    createDynPage(response, "The request type parameter must be insert");
}
```

The table:

[image: Click here to see it]

As you can see from both the code and the table, the column `PROGRAMMEDescription` exists normally. I can't understant why Java think it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked that you're connecting to the correct database and using the correct schema?  *(Also, concatenating strings to make an `INSERT` is **very** bad practice.  You're fundamentally vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks and simple plain text errors caused by strings with `'`, etc.  I strongly urge you to look at parameterised queries / prepared statements.)*

Comment: Also, there is nothing in your image to show the table name.  Are you certain that the table name `CUSTOMERS` is correct?  Being that -every- column is named `PROGRAMME*`, I wouldn't be surprised if you should be inserting in to the `PROGRAMME` table...

Comment: Ooooh I was trying to insert the query in the wrong table all along! I changed CUSTOMERS to PROGRAMME and it worked. It was in front of my eyes and I wasn't seeing it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because the field is not in the database! Perhaps you should get the sql statement executed this time and execute it once in the database to determine whether the field exists in the database!